# match multiple files by the number in filename

Tags: bash

I have many files abc_001.txt, abc_002.txt, ..., abc_999.txt in a directory. How can i select abc_001.txt ... abc_100.txt? i want to copy or tar them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need `abc_0??.txt` and `abc_100.txt` :)

Answer (score 9):

In Bash you can make a list of all numbers in a range: `abc_{001..100}.txt`

Comment: In Bash prior to version 4, the leading zeros get dropped. You can use  `{0{90..99},100}` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cp abc_0[0-9][0-9].txt abc_100.txt destination/
```

... or:

```
tar cvf archive.tar abc_0[0-9][0-9].txt abc_100.txt
```

Comment: This matches `abc_999.txt` which the original post supposes to avoid.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question.  I can correct that, or I'll just delete my answer if you expand yours with similar examples ;)

Comment: Why, I actually upvoted your answer because it shows a certain way of thinking about the problem. Someone else googling for a solution for a similar but not exactly the same problem might find it useful.